# IntersectionObserver superseded by Proxy?

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer, javascript-proxy

It makes sense to me that `IntersectionObserver` is preferred to adding scroll-based event listeners these days. Great.

However, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758085/intersectionobserver-observe-is-not-an-object-how-to-use-intersectionobserver) and [here](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/an-update-on-object-observe) that a `Proxy` offers a more desirable way to do this and that `Object.observe` is perhaps even obsolete.

After reading about `Proxy` traps for a while, I still can't get my head around how I would use them in my imaginary use case below - or find any good references for it.

The imaginary use case:

1. Generate an arbitrary number of `div`s with random background colours.
2. Each `div` gets an `IntersectionObserver`.
3. When `isIntersecting == true` for any of the `div`s, the `body`'s background colour changes to that of the `div`.

**How would I even begin to think about implementing this using proxies?**

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2bywqjr3/2/).
It actually creates an attractive - if counterintuitive - effect.

```
let numberOfDivs = 5;

function createDiv(divNumber) {

    // set the div's tag name, class name and a unique ID
    let aDiv = document.createElement('div');
    aDiv.className = 'my-divs';
    aDiv.id = 'div' + divNumber;

    // set a random hex bg colour for the div;
    // drops a leading zero 1/16 of the time but it's not material to the example
    aDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

    // append the div to the body
    document.body.appendChild(aDiv);

    // set IntersectionObserver on the div
    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(whatsIn, {threshold: 0.5});
    observer.observe(aDiv);

}

// create the divs

for ( let i = 0; i < numberOfDivs; i++ ) {
    let newDiv = createDiv(i);
}

// examine the IntersectionObserver output whenever isIntersecting changes
function whatsIn(payload) {
    console.log("Is " + payload[0].target.id + " intersecting? " + payload[0].isIntersecting);

    // change background color based on most recent isIntersecting == true
    document.body.style.backgroundColor =
        payload[0].isIntersecting
            ? payload[0].target.style.backgroundColor
            : document.body.style.backgroundColor;
}
```

Comment: If we're talking about [this Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), then I honestly don't see how you can replace an IntersectionObserver with that...

Comment: I cant see any reference to proxy in those links

Comment: @JaromandaX Second link, in ESDiscuss. They discuss Proxy and Object.observe a little further down.

Comment: I see how you could use Proxy now, but that's so much more work than using an IntersectionObserver. Also, it's a lot slower (performance-wise).

Comment: @caTS yes it is that Proxy and nor do I.

Comment: @JaromandaX I think I have conflated them, as the SO poster in the first link also seems to have done.

Thank you both for your input on this. At least my instinct was right, even if I confused IntersectionObserver with Object.observe! Haha